# What does it mean for a correspondence to be single valued?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, discrete-mathematics

Let's say we have a correspondence $f:A \rightarrow B$, what would it mean for f to be single valued. Does that mean each element of A gets mapped to a unique subset of B or do all elements of A get mapped to one particular subset in B?

Comment: I think it just means that $f$ is a function (rather than something like $\sqrt x$ which can be understood as having both positive and negative branches).

Comment: ^Not really because a function maps to a unique value whereas a correspondence maps to a set which could have more than one elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *correspondence* $f: A \to B$ is just a subset of $A \times B$. Being single-valued means that if $(a,b) \in f$ and $(a,b') \in f$ for the same $a$, then $b=b'$, so the image of $a$ (if it exists) is uniquely determined and can be denoted by $f(a)$; such a correspondence is often called *functional*. If $f$ is also "total" in the sense that we have such a $b \in B$ for *every* $a \in A$ we call $f$ a *function* from $A$ to $B$. So values can be anything that's in $B$, really.